# TryUpdateModelAsync Opens and closes connection 1000's times

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a section of code...

```
TryUpdateModelAsync(tn.IT_Task, "IT_Task");
```

...that used to work reasonably speedy. Now, that same piece of code is achingly slow. Sometimes up to 10-15 seconds to complete.

Using...

```
DB.ITConsole.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

...to output what was happening in the background, I found that the method was opening and closing the database literally several 1000 times. Seemed to me to be at least as many times as there are "IT_Task" records. Perhaps more. Small sample of the output below...

What's going on? How can I get a single record on the model updated from the views collection?

```
Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Project_Note_ID] AS [Project_Note_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Project_Note] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "164" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Task_ID] AS [Task_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Reported_By_ID] AS [Reported_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[NAB_ID] AS [NAB_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Category_ID] AS [Task_Category_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Type_ID] AS [Task_Type_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Status_ID] AS [Task_Status_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Priority_ID] AS [Task_Priority_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Severity_ID] AS [Task_Severity_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Due] AS [Date_Due]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Task] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "164" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Project_Note_ID] AS [Project_Note_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Project_Note] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "203" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Task_ID] AS [Task_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Reported_By_ID] AS [Reported_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[NAB_ID] AS [NAB_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Category_ID] AS [Task_Category_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Type_ID] AS [Task_Type_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Status_ID] AS [Task_Status_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Priority_ID] AS [Task_Priority_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Severity_ID] AS [Task_Severity_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Due] AS [Date_Due]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Task] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "203" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Task_Note_ID] AS [Task_Note_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_ID] AS [Task_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[CC_User] AS [CC_User]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Task_Note] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Task_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "15669" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Project_Note_ID] AS [Project_Note_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Project_Note] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "235" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Task_ID] AS [Task_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Reported_By_ID] AS [Reported_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[NAB_ID] AS [NAB_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Category_ID] AS [Task_Category_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Type_ID] AS [Task_Type_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Status_ID] AS [Task_Status_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Priority_ID] AS [Task_Priority_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Severity_ID] AS [Task_Severity_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Due] AS [Date_Due]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Task] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "235" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Project_Note_ID] AS [Project_Note_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Project_Note] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "243" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Task_ID] AS [Task_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Reported_By_ID] AS [Reported_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[NAB_ID] AS [NAB_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Category_ID] AS [Task_Category_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Type_ID] AS [Task_Type_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Status_ID] AS [Task_Status_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Priority_ID] AS [Task_Priority_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Severity_ID] AS [Task_Severity_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Due] AS [Date_Due]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Task] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "243" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Project_Note_ID] AS [Project_Note_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Project_Note] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "257" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Task_ID] AS [Task_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Reported_By_ID] AS [Reported_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[NAB_ID] AS [NAB_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Category_ID] AS [Task_Category_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Type_ID] AS [Task_Type_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Status_ID] AS [Task_Status_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Priority_ID] AS [Task_Priority_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Severity_ID] AS [Task_Severity_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Due] AS [Date_Due]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Task] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "257" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Project_Note_ID] AS [Project_Note_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Project_Note] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "285" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

Opened connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Task_ID] AS [Task_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Entered_By_ID] AS [Entered_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Reported_By_ID] AS [Reported_By_ID], 
    [Extent1].[NAB_ID] AS [NAB_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Category_ID] AS [Task_Category_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Type_ID] AS [Task_Type_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Status_ID] AS [Task_Status_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Priority_ID] AS [Task_Priority_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Task_Severity_ID] AS [Task_Severity_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Entered] AS [Date_Entered], 
    [Extent1].[Date_Due] AS [Date_Due]
    FROM [dbo].[IT_Task] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Project_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: "285" (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 15/06/2017 16:59:40 +01:00
```

UPDATE - What am I trying to do with the TryUpdateModelAsync?

To my mind, my knowledge, TryUpdateModelAsync would only do one thing. Apologies if I am wrong.

I have created a model based on a particular record in the database along with some supporting material for dropdowns etc on that page, then sent it to the page for editing during the GET phase. Then during the POST phase I create another (same) model based on the same record.

The TryUpdateModelAsync is intended to take the data from the return POST and update the original record with that data, before I can then save it.

I really wasn't expecting the process to look in the database at all to merge these two sets of data. I would have only expected access to the database to take place upon the SaveChanges.

Comment: Please read [How to use tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) before posting a question and why you shouldn't stuff tags into the title and use the correct tags when asking a question. Tagging a question [tag.entity-framework] when you actually ask about [tag:entityframework-core] will only lead to less or incorrect answers

Comment: Also excuse us if our fortune-telling skills are lacking, but how do you expect us to help, when we don't know what your `TryUpdateModelAsync` method is even doing or which database provider you are using?

Comment: This is actually EF6 issue and not EFCore

Comment: Apologies. I don't post often. One reason I don't post often is because I found over the years there are some pretty rude and unhelpful people often more interested in dragging you down than helping. A bit like grammar police for programmers. I am however a little stuck, slightly bemused and still interested in help if anybody can do so.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on EF6. That's correct, this is EF6, not EF Core. This is a new environment I have recently moved to and I am still getting used to the names and terms of this environment.

Comment: TryUpdateModelAsync and its functionality is actually ASP.NET Core, not EF6 I just found. https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.TryUpdateModelAsync%3CTModel%3E(TModel,String,IValueProvider,Func%3CModelMetadata,Boolean%3E)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem where TryUpdateModelAsync was taking way too long to return.  I figured that the problem was that it was trying to iterate through all the sub collections on my database object, and EF6 was lazy-loading everything along the way.  This appeared to be the case because I got it to work by turning off lazy-loading before I got my object from the database by doing this:

```
 _database.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```